# Re-runnable mysql upgrade script

Tags: mysql

Is there a way in mysql to write a re-runnable sql script?
I tried the : 'IF EXISTS' syntax but that only seems to work for stored procedures.
It doesn't seem the 'select if' syntax will do what I want.

Ideally I would like to do something like:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from table where name='Name') Then insert into table values('Name');
else select 'Name has already been inserted into table';
end if;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the MySQL manual, you can find there everything you need under "control structures"

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO t1 ...
```

You can see from the return whether a row was inserted or not. Note that it requires that there is a unique constraint, otherwise you will just get duplicates. If you have a primary key this is also a unique constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could store your database schema revision in suitable table and use that as a criteria for update processing?

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into myTable(name)
select 'some_name_value' from myTable
where not exists (select 1 from myTable where name = 'some_name_value')
limit 1;
```

would insert value(s) if they don't already exist.

Answer (score -2):

We use a construct like (SQL Server)

```
IF 0 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <your table> WHERE <your condition>)
BEGIN
    <your work here>
END
```

to manage SQL sections we want repeatable.  If the script is re-run and the values are there, the count(*) is not zero and it doesn't do the work again.

Comment: This seems the most promising but is it dependent on a particular version of mysql? It doesn't seem to work in 5.0 ... can you provide a fuller example?

Comment: As I noted, the syntax is from SQL Server.  The *technique* should translate.  I don't know what procedural language, like T/SQL, that MySql provides for flow control.